# Getting document id after querying the Result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to ask one thing is it possible to get the document id of the satisfied conditions
like i have applied a condition on the particular collection and the query is valid and returned documents and I wanted to get the document id which comes after the querying

```
const reports = async() => {
const officeCollection = db.collection('XYZ');
  const officeQuerySnapshot = await officeCollection.where('office','==' ,office).get();
  const officeData = []
  var firstContact= ''
  officeQuerySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    // var firstContact = doc.data().attachment['First Contact']
    // console.log(firstContact)
    officeData.push(doc.data())

  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the document ID, you'll want to use [`doc.id`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#id):

```
const reports = async() => {
const officeCollection = db.collection('XYZ');
  const officeQuerySnapshot = await officeCollection.where('office','==' ,office).get();
  const officeData = []
  var firstContact= ''
  officeQuerySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    console.log(doc.id)
    officeData.push(doc.data())
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you will use `doc.ref` instead of `doc.data()` you will have reference to will get `DocumentReference` object. Than you can get property like `_path` to get document id.

I used something like `console.log(doc.ref._path)` and I get something like that:

[image]

Document ID is in the segment list.
API reference you can find [here.](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html)